# How to use Sphinx to generate PDF

Tags: macos, python-sphinx, pdflatex

I am trying to learn Sphinx documentation creating tool. I am able to generate html documentation. Now, in order to create an off-line version of the (html) documentation, I have been trying to generate pdf file from my project.

Towards that goal, so far I have tried the following (using resources available on the web including the **Sphinx** docs):

Added the following to **conf.py**:

```
# conf.py options for Latex
latex_engine = 'pdflatex'
latex_elements = {
    'papersize': 'a4paper',
    'pointsize': '10pt',
    }
```

Subsequently used the command `make latexpdf` in the terminal, whereupon I got the following messages in the terminal:

```
/Users/.../.../.../.../.../urls.py:docstring of lead.urls:5: WARNING: Definition list ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent.
/Users/.../urls.py:docstring of lead.urls:7: WARNING: Unexpected indentation.
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
processing lead.tex... index modules/... 
resolving references...
done
writing... done
copying TeX support files... copying TeX support files...
done
build succeeded, () warnings.

The LaTeX files are in _build/latex.
Run 'make' in that directory to run these through (pdf)latex
(use `make latexpdf' here to do that automatically).
latexmk -pdf -dvi- -ps-  'lead.tex'
make[1]: latexmk: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [lead.pdf] Error 1
make: *** [latexpdf] Error 2
```

A new folder `latex` was created with a number of files in them including one with the name `<project_name>.tex` (`lead.tex` in the error log above) and one batch file `make.bat` among them.

However, running the command `make` only produces the following error:

```
latexmk -pdf -dvi- -ps-  'lead.tex'
make: latexmk: No such file or directory
make: *** [lead.pdf] Error 1
```

Following some leads (materials available on the web) on `latexmk`, tried to install `BasicTex` package from the [Tex site](https://tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html).

However, the package available is only for macOs 10.13 and higher. I am on `10.12.6`.

So I am stuck. Can somebody please let me know **if there is any solution to my predicament?**

Answer (score 0):

https://www.tug.org/mactex/faq/3-4.html worked for me while on macOS 10.12.6.

Comment: Yeah, I was able to locate the source (the link was towards the end of the MaxTex home in somewhat _fine prints_). However, after "successful" installation I am still getting `sudo: tlmgr: command not found`. I realize it may be an access problem. How do I make my **mac** recognize `tlmgr`? Thanks.

Comment: It should be 2016, not 2019. Something went wrong with the installation. I'd suggest looking at installation documentation for insight. I don't know what else to try.